# kivy: "Invalid property name" error message for a valid property name

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

If I put this into the main program:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def on_focus(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Yay!", args, kwargs)
```

And this into the kv file:

```
#: import MyTextInput __main__.MyTextInput

                MyTextInput:
                    id: e_birth_date
                    text: ""
                    size_hint_x: 1
```

Then the behaviour is correct, this is printed whenever the text input gets or looses the focus:

```
Yay! (<__main__.MyTextInput object at 0x0CC1B8B8>, True) {} 
Yay! (<__main__.MyTextInput object at 0x0CC1B8B8>, False) {}
```

However, this does not work at all:

```
                TextInput:
                    id: e_birth_date
                    text: ""
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    on_focus = root.on_field_focus(*args)
```

Kivy refuses to compile the .kv file with this message:

```
kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "C:\not_telling\app.kv", line 185:
 ...
     183:                        text: ""
     184:                        size_hint_x: 1
 >>  185:                        on_focus = root.on_field_focus(*args)
     186:                    TextInput:
     187:                        id: e_phone
 ...
 Invalid property name
```

Why? Is this a bug?

**UPDATE**: Changed the title so that others can find this easily (as it turned out, it has nothing to do with that particular property name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error, try this:

```
TextInput:
    id: e_birth_date
    text: ""
    size_hint_x: 1
    on_focus: root.on_field_focus(*args)
```

Comment: My fault. I would delete my question immediately, but I won't for one reason. The message says "invalid property name" instead of "Syntax Error". Very confusing!

Comment: I guess everything before the colon is considered as a class name or a property

Comment: and if the compilator does not see the colon he gives the Invalid Property Name message

Comment: But this is bad. In fact, I have never seen a kv file where any of the non-comment lines did not contain a colon. It should be a syntax error, not an "invalid property name"