# Getting a syntax error while using pos_hint in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm in the process of learning how to use kivy and I'm very much interested in knowing how the kivy language works.

Well I was trying to display a couple of labels at specific locations using the FloatLayout. Since the labels have similar properties I created a dynamic class to avoid redundancies. But for some reason when I use my dynamic class I get a syntax error on `pos_hint` for what I believe is valid syntax. But weirdly enough when I use the regular `Label` as the first one and fill in the properties, followed by the dynamic class it works just as I want it to

Here is my test python file:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class floatgameApp(App):
    pass

class PlayGame(FloatLayout):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    floatgameApp().run()
```

Here is the kv file producing the syntax error:

```
<mylabel@Label>:
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "40dp"
    width: "200dp"

PlayGame:

<PlayGame>:
    top_y_pos: 0.98
    FloatLayout:
        mylabel:
            pos_hint :{'center_x': 0.09, 'center_y': root.top_y_pos}
            text: "Score: 0"
        mylabel:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': root.top_y_pos}
            text: "Time: 0"
        mylabel:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': root.top_y_pos}
            text: "Power-Ups"
```

This is the error the above code produces:

```
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': root.top_y_pos}
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the one working properly but looking a little messy:

```
<mylabel@Label>:
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "40dp"
    width: "200dp"

PlayGame:

<PlayGame>:
    top_y_pos: 0.98
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "40dp"
            width: "200dp"            
            pos_hint :{'center_x': 0.09, 'center_y': root.top_y_pos}
            text: "Score: 0"
        mylabel:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': root.top_y_pos}
            text: "Time: 0"
        mylabel:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': root.top_y_pos}
            text: "Power-Ups"
```

In this edited version of my question, I'll like to acknowledge the solution of @SP-SP.

Making the name of the dynamic class begin with a capital letter allows the code to work just fine, even though I'm not sure exactly why. I guess its just going to be one of those object oriented things which is question not the mechanism by which the code works and appreciate its result. Thanks for the help and I do hope this helps someone else

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: the first letter of a custom class must be UpperCase this is an already solved problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236931/kivy-invalid-property-name-error-message-for-a-valid-property-name

Comment: @SP-SP Thanks, your solution works absolutely fine. However I'll like to know if there is any particular reason why it works this way and is it a convention that every class be named beginning with capital letters in the kivy language.

Comment: In the kivy language it is. When you add widgets to a layout that also have property like your `top_pos_y` if there is no distinction between `Widget` and `property` then there will be some problems